# Retrieve list of objects from JsonResult and send to database

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I'm displaying a list of object data in a table that is triggered by a dropdownbox .change function. However, I also need to submit this data to a database. So far, I can display the data when the dropdown changes, but I'm having trouble retrieving the list of objects and sending them to the database upon submit.

You'll notice that one of the properties in the view model is a boolean. This is used to check which Schools are sent to the database.

The last method shown here is called upon submit. When I check which values are being sent to it (through the tmpModel parameter) the Schools list is null. How can I populate this list with the checked Schools?

First, here is the class from my view model that holds the data I want to display and submit.

`public class School
    {
        public int? SchoolId { get; set; }
        public string SchoolName { get; set; }
        public string TownName { get; set; }
        public bool isMoving { get; set; }
    }`

Next, here is the JsonResult method I'm using to get the list of Schools.

```
ReorganizationVm model = new ReorganizationVm(); // an instance of my view model
    public JsonResult Schools(int townCode, int sauId, int fiscalYear)
    {
        using (var service = new ParameterService(this.User))
        {
            try
            {
                model.Schools = new List<School>();
                foreach (var o in service.GetSchools(townCode, sauId, fiscalYear))
                {
                    School School = new School
                    {
                        SchoolId = o.School_ID,
                        SchoolName = o.SchoolName,
                        TownName = o.TownName,
                        isMoving = false
                    };
                    model.Schools.Add(School);
                }

                return Json(model.Schools, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
            return Json(null);
        }
    }
```

Here's JavaScript function that calls the controller method and the table from the view.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        $('#CurrentSau_SauId').change(function () {
            var sauId = $("#CurrentSau_SauId").val();
            var townCode = $("#Town_TownCode :selected").val();
            var fiscalYear = $("#FiscalYear").val();
            var schools = $("#schools");
            $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                type: "GET",
                url: "@(Url.Action("Schools", "Reorganization"))",
                data: { "sauId" : sauId, "townCode" : townCode, "fiscalYear" : fiscalYear },
                success: function (data) {
                    var result = "";
                    schools.html('');
                    $.each(data, function (id, school) {
                        result +=   '<tr><th>Select Schools that are Moving to New SAU</th></tr>' +
                                    '<tr><th>School Name</th><th>Town</th><th>Moving to New SU</th></tr>' +
                                    '<tr><td>' + school.SchoolName + '</td><td>' + school.TownName + '</td><td>' +
                                    '<input type="checkbox"></td></tr>';
                    });
                    schools.html(result);
                },
                error: function (xhr, AJAXOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert('Failed to retrieve schools.');
                }
            });        
        });
    });
</script>

<table id="schools">

</table>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And, lastly, the controller method that is called upon submit. Right now, it's empty because I'm only using it to check which values are getting back.

```
public ActionResult Index(ReorganizationVm tmpModel)
{
    return View();
}
```

***Edit: update****

It's been a while but I've finally had some time to come back to this. After trying the code posted by AmanVirdi, I found that it didn't work. However, I was able to get it to work (for the most part) by adding value attributes to the html. Here is the Jquery that builds the html to be injected into the page. Please also note the `id` variable was changed to `i` and rather than using `html()` to inject the html I'm now using `append()`.

**JQuery**

```
            $.each(data, function (i, school) {
                result +=
                    '<tr><td>' + school.SchoolName +
                    '<input type="hidden" name="SchoolList[' + i + '].SchoolName" id="SchoolList[' + i + ']_SchoolName" />' +
                    '<input type="hidden" name="SchoolList[' + i + '].SchoolId" value="' + school.SchoolId + '" /></td>' +

                    '<td>' + school.Town +
                    '<input type="hidden" name="SchoolList[' + i + '].Town" value="' + school.Town + '" /></td>' +

                    '<td><input type="checkbox" name="SchoolList[' + i + '].IsMoving" value="' + school.SchoolId + '" />';

$("#schools").append(result);
```

As mentioned, it works for the most part. All the values are being sent to the controller **except** the `isMoving` checkbox values remain false for each object in the generated list.

How can I get the `isMoving` values to change according to whether or not the checboxes are checked? I was reading about `CheckBoxListFor` and think it might help me, but I'm generating the html directly rather than using Html helpers. Maybe I could replicate the html generated by a `CheckBoxListFor`. Is this the way to go?

Comment: What if on submit I found the selected schools using Jquery. Then, using the same method used to get all the schools, get only those schools that are associated with the checked indices. My only reservation is that it would require another call back to the Controller.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add four hidden fields for each property in "Schools" model class, in the "result" string. Like this:

**jQuery:**Tests[position].Test.Preconditions"

```
result +='<tr><th>Select Schools that are Moving to New SAU</th></tr>' +
         '<tr><th>School Name</th><th>Town</th><th>Moving to New SU</th></tr>' +
         '<tr><td><input type="hidden" id="SchoolList['+ id +']_SchoolId" name="SchoolList['+ id +'].SchoolId" />' +
         '<input type="hidden" id=""SchoolList['+ id +']_SchoolName" name="SchoolList['+ id +'].SchoolName" />'+school.SchoolName + '</td>' +
         '<td><input type="hidden" id="SchoolList['+ id +']_TownName" name="SchoolList['+ id +'].TownName" />' + school.TownName +'</td>' +
         '<td><input type="checkbox" id="SchoolList['+ id +']_isMoving" name="SchoolList['+ id +'].isMoving" checked="checked"/></td></tr>';
```

**Html**

```
<form action="Controller/Index" method="get">
<!-- <form action="Controller/SaveData" method="get"> for SaveData method -->
  <table id="schools">

  </table>
  <table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Controller**
And add [HttpPost] on the Index method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(ReorganizationVm tmpModel)
{
    return View();
}
```

or you can create a separate action method for saving school data.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveData(ReorganizationVm tmpModel)
{
    // do your stuff here
    return View("Index");
}
```

Change your model somthing like this:

```
public class ReorganizationVm()
{
    public List<Schools> SchoolList { get; set; }
}


ReorganizationVm model = new ReorganizationVm(); // an instance of my view model
    public JsonResult Schools(int townCode, int sauId, int fiscalYear)
    {
        using (var service = new ParameterService(this.User))
        {
            try
            {
                model.Schools = new List<School>();
                foreach (var o in service.GetSchools(townCode, sauId, fiscalYear))
                {
                    School School = new School
                    {
                        SchoolId = o.School_ID,
                        SchoolName = o.SchoolName,
                        TownName = o.TownName,
                        isMoving = false
                    };
                    model.Schools.Add(School);
                }

                return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); //pass whole model variable
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
            return Json(null);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This makes sense, but how could I save only the checked schools.

Comment: `foreach(var school in tmpModel.Schools.Where(x => isMoving)) save(school);`

Comment: @Dleh, how will the isMoving values be set in the model. As it is now all the isMoving values will be false.

Comment: Add  checked attribute in this input <input type="checkbox" id="isMoving" name="isMoving" checked />

Comment: I have edited the code, now it should work. And use foreach as suggested by DLeh in the method where saving the data.